# Naming and variables of config.vm.define

Tags: ruby, configuration, vagrant

In the tutorial 
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/

there are a few examples of code such as

```
config.vm.define :testing do |test|

config.vm.define "web" do |web|
```

In some of these examples, the string  after **define** is the same as after **do** (web, web) , in some it is not (testing, test). Why?

Also, why use quotes with **"web"**  but colon with **:testing** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more ruby language than vagrant, but basically config.vm.define is a method which takes one parameter, then there is a [ruby block statement](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html) and within this block the method parameter has a specific name which is defined between the `|`

> Also, why use quotes with "web" but colon with :testing ?

As a ruby novice, I would say it is the same - the :x is called *symbols* and you can read [some differences about using one or the other](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)